# Webview in a NestedScrollView Talkback - Scrolls only when end of screen is reached

Tags: android, android-webview, android-nestedscrollview, talkback

My layout is like this:

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <WebView>
            <RecyclerView/>
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

The webview contains a list, so when talkback is on, focus will be on the items in that list. The issue I'm having is that it won't scroll down when focus is on the item way below in the screen. It will only scroll when I reach the very last item. Same behavior when going thru the last in reverse.

I noticed that there's no issue scrolling thru the items in the webview when NestedScrollView is removed. But then I can't show what's in my recyclerview.

Is there a property I need to add in the NestedScrollView to resolve the scrolling issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am running into the same issue.